# Copying a set of local files to ftp

Tags: ftp, batch, windows-command-prompt

I want to copy a set of local files to `ftp://124.30.124.230` (it will ask for a username and password). I want to do this work on 400 systems so I have planned to do this work by creating a batch file to do that work. Can anybody help me out with the coding please.

**Update**

I tried the below script, but when I ran it I got an error.

```
lftp -e 'mirror -r C:\Documents and Settings\voyager\Desktop\Ramkrishna\Daily Report /MINDSCAPE/Ramkrishnan/ftp' -u ablftp,(password entered) 124.30.124.230
pause
```

My result was this:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\voyager\Desktop>lftp -e 'mirror -r 'lftp' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

C:\Documents and Settings\voyager\Desktop>C:\Documents and Settings\voyager\Desk top\Ramkrishna\Daily Report /MINDSCAPE/Ramkrishnan/ftp' -u ablftp,(*) 124.30.124.230 'C:\Documents' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Have you done any trial to help you improve it?

Answer (score 0):

my first try would be lftp, using `mirror -r` command.

so you could basicaly create batch file with just

```
lftp -e 'mirror -r /local/path /path/on/ftp' -u user,pass 124.30.124.230
```

and run this on all hosts

Comment: Hi Fox,,Thanks for your reply. I have used your codes like this lftp -e 'mirror -r 
C:\Documents and Settings\voyager\Desktop\Ramkrishna\Daily Report /MINDSCAPE/Ramkrishnan/ftp' -u ablftp,(password entered) 124.30.124.230
pause